# Find out if values in dataframe are between values in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas and i'm trying to understand if there is a method to find out, if two values from one row in df1 are between two values from one row in df2.

Basically my df1 looks like this:

```
start | value | end
1     | TEST  | 5
2     | TEST  | 3
...
```

and my df2 looks like this:

```
start | value | end
2     | TEST2  | 10
3     | TEST2  | 4
...
```

Right now i've got it working with two loops:

```
for row in df1.iterrows():
  for row2 in df2.iterrows():
    if row2[1]["start"] >= row[1]["start"] and row2[1]["end"] <= row[1]["end"]:
      print(row2)
```

but this doesn't feel like it's the pandas way to me.

What I'm expecting is that row number 2 from df2 is getting printed because 3 > 1 and 4 < 5, i.e.:

```
3 | TEST2 | 4
```

Is there a method to do this in the pandas kind of working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a cross [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get all combinations of `df1` and `df2` rows, and filter using classical comparisons. Finally, get the indices and slice:

```
idx = (df1.merge(df2.reset_index(), suffixes=('1', '2'), how='cross')
          .query('(start2 > start1) & (end2 < end1)')
          ['index'].unique()
        )
df2.loc[idx]
```

*NB. I am using `unique` here to ensure that a row is selected only once, even if there are several matches*

output:

```
   start  value  end
1      3  TEST2    4
```